# I don't why i'm having this error, when i post link in my answer

Tags: discussion

[image]**Please help me to resolve this issue. When i post link in my answer then i'm having this error.**[image]

Comment: Try accompanying the link to JSFiddle with code? That is, don't just post the link to JSFiddle. Also include your code in your post. You can edit your initial question post!

Comment: As an aside, the answer you've got there should be fleshed out.  Explain *why* your code will answer the question as opposed to saying "maybe this will help".

Answer (score 4):

If you post a link to jsfiddle.net, you always have to include at least a portion of your code in the answer. To do this, paste your code into your answer, select it, and click the <kbd>{}</kbd> button in the markdown bar above your answer. This will indent any selected text by 4 spaces, which will format it as a code sample. You can also start a code sample without using the <kbd>{}</kbd> button by simply pressing space 4 times at the beginning of each line.

```
This is an example of a code block.
```

Comment: A far superior option is *not using jsfiddle*, and instead putting it in a **stack-snippet**.